# Is it possible to extract Data.Type.Equality pattern-matching into a separate function?

Tags: haskell

For some test code, I wrote a function that allows me to implement polymorphic functions using monomorphic implementations. I implemented it using [`Data.Type.Equality`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html) like this:

```
assertEq :: forall a b. (Show a, Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> (a :~: b)
assertEq x = fromMaybe (error errorMessage) eqT
  where errorMessage =
            "expected value of type ‘" <> show (typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy b))
         <> "’, but got ‘" <> show x
         <> "’, which is of type ‘" <> show (typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy a)) <> "’"
```

Using it looks like this:

```
insertUser :: forall record m. (RelationalEntity record, Monad m) => record -> m (Either (Entity record) (Key record))
insertUser user = case (assertEq user :: record :~: User) of
  Refl -> return . Right $ UserId 1234
```

Importantly, the type signature works for any `RelationalEntity`, but it actually expects a `User`. Normally, this sort of function would be an abomination, but it works great in test code, since any exceptions that are raised will simply make the test fail, which is exactly what I want.

Of course, using `assertEq` is a little wordy. Fortunately, Haskell has referential transparency, so it should be really easy to pack up that `case` match into a helper function, right? Well, I tried to do that:

```
withAssertEq :: forall a b c. (Show a, Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> (b -> c) -> c
withAssertEq x f = case (assertEq x :: a :~: b) of Refl -> f x
```

Now I should be able to use `withAssertEq` from within `insertUser`:

```
insertUser :: forall record m. (RelationalEntity record, Monad m) => record -> m (Either (Entity record) (Key record))
insertUser x = withAssertEq x $ \(_ :: User) ->
  return . Right $ UserId 1234
```

Unfortunately, this does not typecheck. The information the typechecker gains from the `Refl` pattern-match within `withAssertEq` does not propagate to the use within `insertUser`, so the typechecker cannot unify the expected result, `Key record`, with the actual result, `Key User`.

Is there any way to write a function that *can* propagate this sort of type information? Or do I *need* to use a `case` expression directly in order to tell the typechecker about the type equality information?

Comment: I think that in any case you will need to keep `Refl` around, since that is really where the proof of the type equivalence lies...

Comment: `assertEq` looks pointless to me: when `a` and `b` are statically different, instead of generating a type mismatch error, we instead generate a fake witness for their equality, which will call `error` at runtime. This seems to effectively turn a compile-time error into a run-time one, which is a criminal offense in the world of types ;-) So... why should one want to use that? I think I missed the point entirely...

Comment: @chi I agree 100%, which is why I called this an abomination in the question. ;) I normally loathe partial functions of all kinds, but this is code used in my test suite, not a real application. I tried to give more context in the question, but it was too long a cluttered, so I decided to leave it out. I will mostly just have to ask you to trust me that this is not an XY problem. :)

Comment: @AlexisKing You can keep your Haskell membership card. For now. :-PP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [`gcastWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html#v:gcastWith).

```
gcastWith :: a :~: b -> (a ~ b => r) -> r
gcastWith Refl x = x
```

That type takes a bit of reading. `gcastWith` takes an equality proof (`a :~: b`) and a value which typechecks under the assumption that `a ~ b` (`a ~ b => r`) and returns that value with its assumption discharged (`r`).

The only work that's going on in `gcastWith`'s body is pattern-matching on `Refl`. This seeds the context with the `a ~ b` equality in `gcastWith`'s body, which GHC dutifully plumbs into `x`'s type. Pretty cool!

So you can use `gcastWith`'s type as a template for your `withAssertEq`:

```
withAssertEq :: forall a b r. (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Proxy a -> Proxy b -> (a ~ b => r) -> r
withAssertEq _ _ = gcastWith (fromJust eqT :: a :~: b)
```

The `Proxy`s are there to enable call-sites to tell GHC which `Typeable` dictionaries to use for `a` and `b`. The type fails the ambiguity check without them.

The usual caveats apply, don't use partial functions, blah blah blah.

Comment: Ah, perfect, it looks like I missed `gcastWith`, but this is exactly what I was looking for. And yes, partial functions are evil, but see my comment on the question for slightly more context. :)